# TinyMCE repositioning <span> tags

Tags: tinymce

i've seen some TinyMCE editor questions here before, so figured it was kosher.

Using Version 3.1.2

I have a "glossary" I am trying to use and on save, the code is getting repositioned so that portions of the glossary that need to be hidden are not.

It is taking a `<UL>` and placing it outside of a `<span>` tag I have.

The following code:

```
<p class="hide_def">
<span class="term_title">Investigational</span><br>
<span class="def">Definition Here
<ul>
<li>Definition Bullet Point</li>
</ul>
</span>
</p>
```

Is being changed to the snippet below. This throws all of the `<UL>` tags outside of the definition area.:

```
<p class="hide_def">
<span class="term_title">Investigational</span><br>
<span class="def">Definition Here</span></p>

<ul>
<li>Bullet Point</li>
</ul>
```

I have heard of turning off the "cleaning" config setting in TinyMCE, but also heard that is a bad idea.

What can I do here?

Answer (score 0):

Since tinymce version 3.4 deactivation of the cleanup functionality is not apossible anymore.
With your version you can set the tinymce config param cleanup to false:

```
cleanup: false,
```